# How to correctly configure a Visual Studio project using Meson

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, build, meson-build

I am currently trying to build a VS solution using Meson, my project looks like this :

```
SolutionDir
    meson.build
    Library
        meson.build
        headers
            dir1
                .h
            dir2
                .h
        source
            dir1
                .cpp
            dir2
                .cpp
```

Currently, meson.build simply grabs the source files, adds include directories and creates a library.

1- Is it possible to keep this structure with the VS backend ? The generated solution completely ignores the subdirectories (but the files are added properly).

2- Is it possible to add multiple configurations (debug, release etc) to a single project, instead of building a solution for each configuration ?

3- The option `cpp_std=` seems to get ignored without a warning, do I have to specify `/std:` as an argument to the compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

For (1) VS can't help you with the structure, you have to do that manually. Right click on the node in solution explorer where you want a new folder, under add new item select 'Filter' and give the new folder a name. You can then move items within the solution layout using copy-paste.

For (2) configuration management is dealt with at the solution level. You can add new configurations to a project using the project properties window but you would then have to assign newly created configurations (using the Configuration Manager found at Build->Configuration Manager) to a solution configuration in order for VS to actually use the new project configuration. Alternatively you can just do both using Configuration Manager.